# Javascript in Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to write a action method returning Javascript.
How to run javascript using MVC controller?

I tried the following, but it fails to work properly. It shows file download - security warning?

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
  public ActionResult About(clsABC param)
  {
        string message = "Hello! World.";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");             
        return JavaScript(sb.ToString());   
   }
```

Any solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Do try to call the action via Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load and execute the JavaScript with [jQuery getScript method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). In that case you can just write the script that you want to be executed in your action and call it with jQuery.

```
$.getScript("/Controller/Action", function(){
    alert('Script was loaded');
  });
});
```

If you load the script on button click don't forget to call `preventDefault` method like this. This will prevent download file dialog from showing in your case.

```
$('selector here').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...Do your stuff...
  }             
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [post](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-03-cs.aspx)

The ASP.NET MVC framework supports several types of action results including:

1. ViewResult – Represents HTML and markup.
2. EmptyResult – Represents no result.
3. RedirectResult – Represents a redirection to a new URL.
4. JsonResult – Represents a JavaScript Object Notation result that can be used in an AJAX application.

**5. JavaScriptResult – Represents a JavaScript script.**

6. ContentResult – Represents a text result.
7. FileContentResult – Represents a downloadable file (with the binary content).
8. FilePathResult – Represents a downloadable file (with a path).
9. FileStreamResult – Represents a downloadable file (with a file stream).

Hope it helps